# Unity Assembly Reference Error when using Dot syntax c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem that is related to the Dot Syntax.

I have this condition (I am only pasting the relevant code parts):

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;
using Assets.Code.Scripts;
using System.Collections;  // dicionario
using System.Collections.Generic;  // dicionario

namespace Assets.Code.States

if (LoadDiagram.diagramaCarga.TryGetValue(gametime, out test)) // Returns true.
            {
                GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 650, 275, 50, 25),  test.ToString ());
            }
```

And then I have the script where this LoadDiagram is stored:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;
using System.Collections;  // dicionario
using System.Collections.Generic;  // dicionario
using System;
namespace AssemblyCSharp
{
    public class LoadDiagram
    {
        public LoadDiagram ()
        {
            Dictionary<int, float> diagramaCarga = new Dictionary<int, float>();

            diagramaCarga.Add(0, 4.2F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(1, 4F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(2, 3.6F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(3, 3.4F);
        }
    }
}
```

This connection between scripts is not working, I get this error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Scripts' does not exist in the namespace`Assets.Code'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

In the folder Code, there is a folder named scripts where this LoadDiagram is stored, so I don't know how to fix this. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You may get more relevant answers if you posted the actual code; the snippets in their current state are invalid, re: `if (LoadDiagram.diagramaCarga.TryGetValue(gametime, out test))` should be in a class within a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your file LoadDiagram is in a folder Scripts, it is not in the namespace "Scripts". To do that, replace the namespace "AssemblyCSharp" with "Assets.Code.Scripts", or just remove that using statement.

Comment: I had tried that before with no success but it works now, I think that the changes we're not updated

Answer (score 1):

`LoadDiagram` appears to be in the `AssemblyCSharp` namespace from the 2nd code snippet. Change the namespace from `AssemblyCSharp` to `Assets.Code.Scripts` and that should resolve the error.